# how to implement 4-D convolutional kernal

Tags: computer-vision, neural-network, video-processing, deep-learning, caffe

The convolutional kernel in prototxt file needs only setting height and weight of image and the third dimension can be automatically set.

But how do I set 4-D kernel in prototxt file ?

In the figure
[image: early fusion]
the input video is 4-D.

The [the work](http://vision.stanford.edu/pdf/karpathy14.pdf)
says the dimension of first convoltional layer is 4-D.

I have stuck in the issue for two weeks and I'm kind of desperate.

Can anyone help me ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Caffe supports blobs with more than 4 dimensions. If you want to perform temporal convolutions, I suppose you'll need to feed caffe with 5D input blobs with dimensions `batch`-`channels`-`time`-`height`-`width`. With this kind of input you can have temporal convolutions simply by changing the default [`axis`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L588) argument in the `convolution_param`. For example:

```
input: "data"
input_shape: { dim: 5 dim: 15 dim: 3 dim: 227 dim: 227 }
layer {
  name: "temporal_conv"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "temporal_conv"
  param { lr_mult: 1 decay_mult: 1 }
  param { lr_mult: 2 decay_mult: 0 }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 32
    kernel_size: 3 kernel_size: 5 kernel_size: 5
    pad: 1 pad: 2 pad: 2
    stride: 1 stride: 2 stride: 2
    axis: 1
  }
}
```

This `"temporal_conv"` layer uses 3x5x5 kernel (pads the input accordingly) and stride 2 in the spatial domain and 1 in the temporal dimension.

Comment: +1, I never knew we could have 4D blobs with convolution. I was with the assumption that the weight should be present in 3D format and then split it accordingly or something other technique along those lines!

Answer (score 0):

@Shai Thank you for replying! I use HDF5 fromat in data layer for training. Tha data store as five dimensions with the order batch-channels-time-height-width. The prototxt part is

```
layer {
    name: "data"
    type: "HDF5Data"
    top: "data"
    top: "label"
    include: {
        phase: TRAIN
    }
    hdf5_data_param {
        source: "path/to/txt"
        batch_size: 50
    }
}
```

and I got the error

```
I0520 21:39:35.705278 30447 net.cpp:84] Creating Layer conv1
I0520 21:39:35.705286 30447 net.cpp:381] conv1 <- data
I0520 21:39:35.705294 30447 net.cpp:339] conv1 -> conv1
I0520 21:39:35.705307 30447 net.cpp:113] Setting up conv1
F0520 21:39:35.705329 30447 base_conv_layer.cpp:14] Check failed: 4 == bottom[0]->num_axes() (4 vs. 5) Input must have 4 axes, corresponding to (num, channels, height, width)
```

It seems the input blob dimension should be 4. Is there any solution?